# Jquery autocomplete with ColdFusion not displaying the results

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, autocomplete, cfc

I have been trying to create an autocomplete using jQuery with ColdFusion as the datasource. I used other scenarios on stackoverflow but it just doesn't seem to work. I can get the results to display in firebug but the autocomplete values aren't displaying after I type 3 characters.

Here is my CFC:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="lookupOrg" access="remote" returntype="String" >
        <cfargument name="search" type="any" required="false" default="">

        <!--- Define variables --->
        <cfset var data="">
        <cfset var result=ArrayNew(1)>

        <!--- Do search --->
        <cfquery name="data">
            SELECT name
            FROM org
            WHERE lower(name) LIKE '#ARGUMENTS.search#%'
            ORDER BY name
        </cfquery>

        <!--- Build result array --->
        <cfloop query="data">
            <cfset returnStruct = StructNew() />
            <cfset returnStruct["label"] = name />

            <cfset ArrayAppend(result,returnStruct) />
        </cfloop>

        <!--- And return it --->
        <cfreturn serializeJSON(result) />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Here is my jQuery & HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#Org').autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
              $.ajax({
                url: "getData.cfc?method=lookupOrg&returnformat=json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                  search: request.term,
                  maxRows: 10
                },
                success: function(data) {
                  response(data);
                }
              });
            },
            parse: function(data) {
              return $.map(data, function(item) {
                return {
                  data: item,
                  value: item,
                  result: item
                };
              });
            }
          });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="span9">
            <input size="34" type="text" name="Org" id="Org" value="" />
        <div id="results"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what is showing up in Firebug when I type in "tes" but the autocomplete isn't displaying any values. Any help will be great!

[{"label":"TEST, L.L.C"}]

Comment: post your full json data.

Comment: Not related to your question, but 1 - use query parameters, 2 - var the returnStruct variable, and 3 - make the search argument mandatory and take away the default value.

Answer (score 2):

I take it that you're using jQueryUI's autocomplete widget since you're including jQuery UI. I don't think that it has a `parse` option or method or event (1)(http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). Therefore your jQuery code should be as follows:

```
        $('#Org').autocomplete(
            {source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "getData.cfc?method=lookupOrg&returnformat=json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                    search: request.term,
                    maxRows: 10
                },
                success: function(data) {
                  response($.map(data, function(item) {
                     return { label: item.label, value: item.label };
                  }));
                }                   
            })
         }
      });
```

And would it be easier on your network if your were transmitting just an array of names?

```
    <cfloop query="data">
        <cfset ArrayAppend(result, name) />
    </cfloop>
```